# Can I sync a CalDav calendar with Google Calendar?

Tags: synchronization, calendar, owncloud

I have what I was hoping could be a shared family calendar set up on OwnCloud. I have no problem syncing it to Sunbird and my phone, but my spouse uses Google Calendar (ie. http://calendar.google.com) for everything and he can't subscribe to CalDav calendars, as far as I can tell.

I can [get an ics feed out of OwnCloud](https://github.com/owncloud/documentation/issues/603) by adding `?export` to the CalDav URL, which is handy, but that produces a read-only feed.

Is there a straightforward (or convoluted) way for me to allow him read and edit a caldav calendar within Google Calendar?